# Development Environment SMTP Server - Rewrite email recipient address

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010, web

I am looking for a way to setup an SMTP server in our development environment that will run on the local dev server and rewrite the recipient email address to our debug address, without effecting the rest of our network. We are developing with ColdFusion, so we can set the SMTP server to be localhost, so should that prevent the SMTP server from effecting our MS Exchange 2010 server?

Obviously the second part to this question is what SMTP server could be used in a windows environment to do this? I know at my previous job we ran local SMTP servers on our development machines but I cant remember the name of the program we were using.

Cheers all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do this:

1. Set a debug mode variable in a configuration file.  If tested as true, rewrite the recipient address in the mail routine.  I've done this on several custom apps (for various other application-specific debugging modes to see SQL output, headers, etc.).
2. Setup the SMTP Virtual service that comes with IIS to be "authoritative" for *.com, *.net, *.org, etc. (basically all the TLDs you would send mail to) and setup ColdFusion to use localhost for the mail server.  the SMTP virtual service will drop the .EML message into the queue, which you can open and view using any mail client.
3. Setup a Postfix box for your developers to use and [configure address rewriting](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) (and set your Exchange box as the smarthost).  I know it's not Windows like you asked, but you could throw it on any old Pentium 3 or 4 workstation as I'm assuming you're not pushing huge volumes of email during development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendmail and the UserDB [configuration](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/) file option.

Comment: Please consider the answer withdrawn. Only now I noticed the MS Exchange 2010 requirement (I've retagged the question appropriately).